# How Convert all Microsoft Flow Questions to a Table Automatically?

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-forms

I am trying to do something that I thought to be simple but I can't figure it out. I just to to GRAB all the question from a Microsoft Form and send the results by email. But I want to make in a way that if we create a new question in the future the email automatically detects the new question.

This is how far as I could get, I expected this to work:

[image]

I don't want to create a static email template, because if can easy be outdated. I want it to be dynamic.

Comment: **This isn't a neat way**. The only possible suggestion I can think of until MS Developers make some updates is by treating the form response body as a string and using the necessary string functions like split,replace, etc to get the list of question ids. 
After which you can use that list to create your dynamic items.